# How to visualize data dependencies

Tags: dependencies, visualization, graph-visualization

Is there any way to Visualize Data Dependencies Diagrammatically? 
Are there any tools which are available for it?
I have some relations which I need to represent Diagrammatically. I used one tool named as Circo for it. Now the other tools which are available ask for code input, I Don't want that. It would be great if someone helps.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your wanting a zero-code solution but usually there's always something that needs fiddling with. One solution I would recommend is the Kibana dashboard with Elasticsearch as the database. ES enables you to store "unstructured" data while Kibana has built-in search query bar and graphing tools that support "group by" out of the box.

Comment: My relations are not any SQL data, they are actually some information from the modules that i extract and from there i come to know, which parameter is dependent upon the other. For circo i manually changed my data into a table representation because that is what it needed for the input , i can do it manually for other tools as well, as long as they do not ask for a code as input because i dont have any code to input. They are just simple relations.